# Web Platform Installer wants to install MySql even though it's already there

Tags: wordpress, windows-server-2016, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to use Web Platform Installer to install WordPress on my Server 2016 system.  When I run it, the first thing it asks for under prerequisites is to install MySql, which it says is not installed.

The problem is that I'm also running hMailServer on this system, and have an existing instance of MySql running for that.  The MySql service is identified as "MySQL57" - I don't know if that's why WPI is not seeing it as installed or not.

At any rate, I don't want to risk disrupting my mail server by letting WPI overwrite the working installation of MySql.

Incidentally, I know little about WPI. I'm just trying to follow the cookbook formulas I find in various blog posts.  That seems to be the accepted way to install WordPress.

Can anyone give advice?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I tried WPI it forced the prereq installation.

I suggest to simply keep your mysql and upload the wordpress package to do the install, its easy to do, you unzip the file and run a script. The install script will ask for the mysql instance login information.

Just be sure to make the directory of wordpress on IIS open on write temporally to allow the script to work.

WPI is good on some instance, but you cant know what it do in the background, to secure a webserver I hate that.

Make sure PHP work before installing wordpress, as its a prereq.